# How could c++ std::bind return value assigned to std::function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, stl, bind

Consider some easy code below:

```
int f1(int a) {
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main (int agrc, char* argv[]) {
  std::function<int(int)> f = std::bind(&f1, std::placeholders::_1);
  f(123);

  return 0;
}
```

I've read some documents about std::function and std::bind, but still don't understand how does it work.
The compiler shows that call of std::bind returns an object of type _Bind_helper, however, I don't see the std::function class has a construction function with input type _Bind_helper, so how does the std::function xxx = std::bind xxx work?

Comment: `std::function` has a constructor template taking any callable functor type.

Comment: Just a passing note: using `std::bind` here is unnecessary. `std::function<int(int)> f(f1);` will do exactly the same thing, without the overhead that `std::bind` adds.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see the std::function class has a construction function with input type _Bind_helper, so how does the std::function xxx = std::bind xxx work?

It does have such constructor. It's this one:

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

Note that this converting constructor participates in overload resolution only if the (deduced) template argument is a Callable - which the return type of `std::bind` is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ccpreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

> Class template `std::function` is a general-purpose polymorphic function
>   wrapper. Instances of `std::function` can store, copy, and invoke any
>   Callable target -- **functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or
>   other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and
>   pointers to data members.**
>
> The stored callable object is called the target of std::function. If a
>   `std::function` contains no target, it is called empty. Invoking the
>   target of an empty std::function results in `std::bad_function_call`
>   exception being thrown.
>
> std::function satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and
>   CopyAssignable.

`std::function` is basically a wrapper around a callable object. It's known as a type erasure object - it erases the details of operations to provide a common interface.

Your `std::bind` expression

```
std::bind(&f1, std::placeholders::_1)
```

produces a function object that calls the function `f1` with a parameter that you provide in a placeholder and the return type is `int`. Hence you can assign that to a function object with the same signature:

```
std::function<int(int)>
```

which uses a constructor that take a callable object.